# Novice CSS - how to align my menu in Ubershop-Child Style Sheet

Tags: javascript, css, menu

I have created a child theme which I am using for a new website build. At the moment the menu is aligning as you can see here http://test.card-cutters.co.uk/

How can I add the relevant code to the style sheet to ensure that the logo and menu items are aligned alongside each other?

My child theme style sheet is currently empty.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

```
div#centre-logo {
    float: left;
}
```

And add a float right to your menu.

Comment: My logo is floating left which is fine, i need the primary menu to be aligned on the same line and not underneath?

Comment: Simply add this property and you will see your menu on the same line

Comment: Doesn't make any difference whatsoever?